# Is it safe to run an instant power supply (IPS) with a flooded lead acid tubular battery (12V, 100 AH) in a small flat/apartment?

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I live in a place where blackouts and power outages occur every hour. For  backup power for two lights and two ceiling fans, I want to buy an IPS that runs on a flooded tubular acid battery, but I have recently read that they emit fumes and are not recommended for any indoor use. I am very concerned now. What should I do?

Comment: What is an IPS? Perhaps you mean UPS, which is an _uninterruptible_ power supply.

Comment: @JYelton Instant Power Supply. It has a larger delay time than UPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lights and a couple of fans, I would just use 12-volt-DC lights and fans, run them straight off the battery, and have the charger operate *when able*.  It's fine to charge while discharging.

As to your question about off-gassing, **that's all about the quality of the battery charger**.  I remember car alternators that had clacky-clack *relay-based* regulators.  They were a complete disaster - constantly overcharged the battery, which creates hydrogen and oxygen and splatters acid out the tops.  We had to add water every month to make up for the hydrolysis and splatters.   But today, alternators are *so good* that they never overcharge, batteries never use up water, I haven't checked water in a battery for 20 years.

Charge control got *so good* that it actually became possible to have *sealed* lead-acid batteries, in which it is impossible to add water. They aren't magic; if they're overcharged they'll boil off their electrolyte and be destroyed since they can't be refilled. They just depend on the fact that most modern chargers are *really good* and tend not to overcharge them.

So yeah, if you use a quality 3-stage battery charger that is state of the art, you won't have much boiling off of hydrogen and oxygen, and so not much acid splatter.  Still, would be wise to get a battery box for it. Don't put electronics in the battery box.

Of course you could also get a cheap battery charger and then have big and expensive problems.  Your call.